# How to ignore some .gz files using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, gzip

I have an s3 bucket where we store gzipped files.

The path format looks something like this - `s3://bucket-name/yyyy-MM-dd/hh/mm/` and it contains lots of gz files.

We read it an hourly level using Spark -

```
val path = "s3://bucket/2022-01-02/19/*" // hourly path
val df   = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                     .option("header", "false")
                     .option("inferSchema", "true")
                     .option("delimiter", "|")
                     .load(path)
println(tsDf.columns.size) // 111
```

There is no issue with the above path, hence it prints 111.

```
val path = "s3://path-temp/2022-01-02/20/*" // hourly path
val df   = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                     .option("header", "false")
                     .option("inferSchema", "true")
                     .option("delimiter", "|")
                     .load(path)
println(tsDf.columns.size) // 34
```

There is an issue in the above path, therefore it prints 34. The complete path looks something like this `s3://path-temp/2022-01-02/20/00/*.gz`, one of the gz files contains 34 columns while all other contains 111 columns which causes spark to read only 34 columns at an hourly level.

How can I make this more robust such that files with fewer columns are skipped by Spark?

Comment: Can you move the one file containing 34 columns to another partition and only read from the partition containing 111 columns?

Comment: No, there are lots of gz files and the expectation is all of them contains 111 columns but sometimes due to some issue one of the file gets fewer columns. Was looking for some Spark property that we can leverage or maybe read it in some other way.

Comment: Hmm, is there any overlap in the schemas? Are you able to post a mock schema (similar to your productions schema, doesn't have to be exact, as long as the types match) of a couple of columns that can be used to determine if there is any overlap?